# Condition on array passed as argument to lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, lambda

I want to put a condition inside my lambda function

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

def my_func():
    return lambda x: np.sin(x) if x < np.pi else np.cos(x)
    
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = my_func()
plt.plot(x, y(x))
plt.show()
```

As I am passing an array '**x**' to the lambda function, it obviously gives an array of ambiguous/multiple truth values and suggests using any() or all(). But that doesn't serve my purpose.

How can I achieve the desired outcome? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [`numpy.piecewise` function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html).

Comment: This does provide the desired outcome in this example but I need to have a lambda function in return for my main program, whereas the numpy.piecewise gives the evaluated array.

Comment: Would it be a solution if you replace `y(x)` with [`numpy.apply_along_axes(y, 0, x)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)?

Comment: What's so special about a `lambda`?  `lambda` is just a 1 line method of defining a function.  You are plotting an array, the result of `y(x)`, not `y`.  It's the `if x<pi` that's producing the ambiguity error when `x` is an array.

Comment: @Enzo, `apply_along_axis` passes a 1d array to the function, iterating over the other dimensions.  It is not a speed tool.  Don't recommend it.

Comment: @hpaulj Where did speed was mention?

Comment: You could write `myfunc` to iterate on `x` and return an array (or even list) of the desired `sin` or `cos`.

Comment: @Enzo, what's the point to using this `apply...` on a 1d `x`?

Comment: @hpaulj The same point of OP's requiring a lambda. Since this function is not deprecated, what's the problem about recommending it when it solves OP's problem while filling the requirements?

Comment: @Enzo, it doesn't solve the OP's problem.  See the addtion to my answer.

Comment: @Enjo, this is actually a made-up example. So my interest here is not to plot y(x), rather generate a (lambda) function that can provide a specific form of the function based on the condition on argument array x. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this function:

```
In [257]: def myfunc():
     ...:     def foo(x):
     ...:         res = [np.sin(i) if i<np.pi else np.cos(i) for i in x]
     ...:         return np.array(res)
     ...:     return foo
     ...: 
In [258]: y=myfunc()
In [260]: y(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi,5))
Out[260]: 
array([ 0.0000000e+00,  1.0000000e+00, -1.0000000e+00, -1.8369702e-16,
        1.0000000e+00])
```

I guess that could be written as `lambda`; but what's the point?  `lambda` is just a way of writing an "anonymous" one line function.  Otherwise there's nothing special about that syntax.

`piecewise` can do the same thing; we could also `where` or other masking to select values from `sin` and `cos`.  But my main point is that "lambda" isn't something special, and secondarily that something as simple as list comprehension gets around the ambiguity error.

```
In [268]: def myfunc():
     ...:     return lambda x: np.where(x<np.pi, np.sin(x), np.cos(x))
              # alt: lambda x: np.sin(x, where=x<np.pi, out=np.cos(x))

In [270]: myfunc()(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,5))
Out[270]: 
array([ 0.0000000e+00,  1.0000000e+00, -1.0000000e+00, -1.8369702e-16,
        1.0000000e+00])
```

### for Enzo

Enzo suggested `apply_along_axes`.  While I objected that it doesn't help with speed, but more importantly it doesn't help here.

```
In [261]: def my_func():
     ...:     return lambda x: np.sin(x) if x < np.pi else np.cos(x)
     ...: 
In [262]: y=my_func()
In [263]: y(0)
Out[263]: 0.0
```

Wrong name:

```
In [265]: np.apply_along_axes(y, 0, np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,5))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-265-24f826b71908>", line 1, in <module>
    np.apply_along_axes(y, 0, np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,5))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 303, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'apply_along_axes'
```

But we still get the ambiguity error:

```
In [266]: np.apply_along_axis(y, 0, np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,5))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-266-fca42b21012f>", line 1, in <module>
    np.apply_along_axis(y, 0, np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,5))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in apply_along_axis
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 379, in apply_along_axis
    res = asanyarray(func1d(inarr_view[ind0], *args, **kwargs))
  File "<ipython-input-261-ac6ffeefd41a>", line 2, in <lambda>
    return lambda x: np.sin(x) if x < np.pi else np.cos(x)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Why?  Because `apply` is designed to pass a 1d array to the function.  It works with 2d arrays, but is better for 3d (or larger) where nested iterations look messy.  With a 1d input, it just passes that whole array:

```
In [267]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:str(x), 0, np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,5))
Out[267]: 
array('[0.         1.57079633 3.14159265 4.71238898 6.28318531]',
      dtype='<U56')
```

With the dimension addition `apply...` does work.  But usually when people have problems with `apply...` they are aiming for a speed improvement ("vectorization").  They think, or at least hope, it will be faster than a simple iteration.  It might not be deprecated, but it sure could use some disclaimers!

```
In [292]: y=my_func()
In [293]: timeit np.array([y(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 5)])
88.7 µs ± 966 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [294]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(y, 0, [np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 5)])
181 µs ± 134 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: How's your solution is betten than mine if you're not using a `lambda` as OP required? To fix my solution, just do `np.apply_along_axis(y, 0, [np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 5)])` and OP's fine.

Comment: numpy.where helped me retain the lambda function and apply the conditional. I know lambda is not needed per se, and so the solution with a sub function defined as foo also works for that matter. I am surprised I have used both these things before, but couldn't think about this for this particular problem. Thanks!